# include simulating a forward in PHP on MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, include, forwarding

If one attempting MVC in PHP just adds `include 'view.php';` at the end of a `controller.php` file, can that be considered a forwarding, therefore still MVC?

Comment: Id say no as the view is now part of the controller, and the controller now depends on that file to work.

Comment: How else would you get access to different classes/objects without doing a require/include? I would recommend using require_once though instead of include.

Comment: @Lawrence: In MVC controllers SHOULD be deciding what views to use. You don't have to tightly couple them using includes directly in your controller though. I would personally make a view controller which decides which view is the correct one and subsequently loads the correct content.

Comment: @ChrisChristensen yeah obviously but hard coding an `include('view.php')` at the end of the controller like the OP says should not be done. What if more then 1 view is required to compile the whole document, At least have a method that passes vars defined in the controller to the view. like 99.9% of mainstream MVC frameworks

Answer (score 1):

No. Not really.

The responsibility of controller in MVC and MVC-inspired patterns is to alter the state of current view instance and the model layer. It has nothing to do with "forwarding".

Views and controllers, while tied to each-other, are not the same thing. When you are using "include" (by default) you are adding file to be a part of the code in which it was executed.

Basically, in your current setup, there is no separation between view instance and controller instance.